# How can I tell if a GWT HTML's contents overflow horizontally?

Tags: gwt, widget

In my GWT project, I have an HTML object which I am trying to display in a FocusPanel. Word wrapping in the HTML object is deliberately switched off.

I would like to know how to tell if the text overflows the window on the right hand side.

I've tried this:

```
final int width = label.getOffsetWidth();
final int pWidth=Window.getClientWidth();
if (width>pWidth)
{
    //Take action if there's an overflow
}
```

but unfortunately the window's width and the Label's width are always coming out the same, regardless of whether the text is contained within the window's boundaries or not.

So how can I tell actually how wide the Label's content is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [GWT Label Widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Label.html) for your `label` it is actually rendered as a `<div/>` so it's width will always be equal to the outer div width. Use the [GWT InlineLabel Widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineLabel.html) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm using HTML actually rather than Label but Label is the superclass.

Comment: @NeilSands same thing. HTML widget uses a `div` to render. You need something (InlineLabel or custom widget) that will render an inline element, such as a `span` or `label`. Alternatively, you can try setting the `display` CSS style on your HTML widget to `inline`.